# python method name dynamically execute - what sort of vulnerability can I expect?

Tags: python

I am trying to maintain function of a class in a dict which I can execute dynamically to get the value. My objective is to add new method names to the dict and be able to execute methods just by passing keys to getVal to reduce imports. Since the class object is not known till getVal() is invoked, I am not able to find a way to import it from the start.

Can you please suggest if this code will be vulnerable and if there is a better way to accomplish this.

The method getVal() will be returning values to caller only as an utility method. Though I am not planning to allow methods that set data, there is no restriction planned to be set in place.

The code is as below:

```
from collections import namedtuple

METHOD = namedtuple('METHOD', ["stringified_method_name", ])
config = {
    "test": METHOD(stringified_method_name="B.C.test")
}


class A():
    class B():
        class C():
            def test():
                return "success"


def getMethodReference(context, stringified_method_name):
    if stringified_method_name:
        part_attribute = stringified_method_name.split(".")
        try:
            if len(part_attribute) > 1:
                method = getMethodReference(context, part_attribute[0])
                return getMethodReference(method, ".".join(part_attribute[1:]))
            elif len(part_attribute) == 1:
                return getattr(context, part_attribute[0])
            else:
                return None
        except AttributeError:
            return None
    else:
        return None


def getVal(context, key):
    method = getMethodReference(context, config[key].stringified_method_name)
    if method:
        return method()
    else:
        return None


print(getVal(context=A(), key="test"))
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Oh this is going to quickly become a pain to maintain. Unforseen bugs are going to be rife in this code as it's testability quickly becomes a gargantuan task. That's not even addressing how the getVal method is used elsewhere in your program. You are exposing the methods to the potential of an end user being able to start probing for methods and what their outputs are.

Comment: Thank you @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim for your comment. Yes, that is a possibility. The getVal here is supposed to be getters only and not exposed to outside directly but as a utility to be consumed internally by other methods. While trying to build something to remove code duplication, I ended up like this. I intended to build a utility that would execute any existing method based on config dict settings where I can pass the function to be executed. The only thing that I foresee to change with this utility is the config.